# Merge all identical strings in "Chart"

Tags: c#, bar-chart

I ran into the problem that each new row is added to the chart as a new value. Is it possible to combine all the elements of the "сoach" column, which are similar in content, and also sum up the "total" column according to them, which is followed by the rating.

```cs
private void fillshar()
{
    // I am using query to postgresql.
    string selectQuery = "SELECT сoach,total FROM groupfit";
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
    NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    //chartRate - is an element "Chart"
    chartRate.DataSource = table;
    chartRate.Series["total"].XValueMember = "сoach";
    chartRate.Series["total"].YValueMembers = "total";
    chartRate.Titles.Add("Rating of the most popular trainers");
}
```

**сoach** - this column is a string that is always repeated in the table, but I want all similar elements to be combined when displayed on the "Chart".

**total** - this is a numerical element, which also needs to be summed according to "сoach ", and according to this parameter, they are sorted by "Chart".

[image: View of entries in the table.]
[image: View of records on the chart]

Comment: Can you give example values from the table as well as the results you're looking for?

Comment: Very unclear question - presumably you are using some specific component (type of `chartRate` is not shown), it is unclear if you want to group data as part of the query or rendering, what DB you are using... Consider to [edit] the question with the details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added details about this issue. It is important to fully open up the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
chartRate.DataSource = table;
chartRate.Series["total"].XValueMember = "сoach";
chartRate.Series["total"].YValueMembers = "total";
chartRate.Titles.Add("Rating of the most popular trainers");
```

With

```
Dictionary<string, int> coaches = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string coach = table.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    int total = int.Parse(table.Rows[i][1].ToString());

    if (!coaches.ContainsKey(coach))
        coaches.Add(coach, 0);

    coaches[coach] += total;
}

DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.Columns.Add("coach");
newTable.Columns.Add("total");

foreach (string coach in coaches.Keys)
{
    newTable.Rows.Add(coach, coaches[coach]);
}

chartRate.DataSource = newTable;
chartRate.Series["total"].XValueMember = "сoach";
chartRate.Series["total"].YValueMembers = "total";
chartRate.Titles.Add("Rating of the most popular trainers");
```

Comment: You are very cool, but unfortunately there is a crash: "System.ArgumentException: 'Column with name 'сoach' was not found.'"

Comment: Everything is fine, I rewrote "сoach" and everything works. I am very grateful for your help, have a nice day.